# Compiling PHP 5.3.3 on mac os snow leopard. Issue with iconv linking

Tags: php, compilation, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to recompile PHP 5.3.3 on mac os snow leopard with iconv and getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_ctor in iconv.o
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      __php_iconv_appendl in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_appendl in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
     (maybe you meant: __libiconv_version)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_mime_decode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_dtor in iconv.o
```

I know it's old problem and I could not find the right solution in google.

Any ideas how to fix it will be appreciated.

I'm using:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5 --with-iconv=/usr/local --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-pdo --with-gd=/usr/local --with-zlib --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-mhash --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-t1lib=/usr/local --with-xsl --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local --with-gettext --with-bz2=/usr --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-cgi --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --enable-sqlite-utf8 --enable-cli --enable-wddx --enable-zip
```

And I have recompiled libiconv 1.13.1 as well.

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, but I'm working on the same problem. So far I've tried patching iconv (instructions at fabien.potencier.org/article/37/php-5-3-0-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard) and editing the iconv.c file (instructions at bill.eccles.net/bills_words/2010/01/building-a-mac-os-x-server-106.html) I'm still seeing the same errors. Let me know if you find any additional answers. I'll post back with same. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but I filed a bug report that may help because I think if you remove openssl support that it'll work. Maybe. We'll see what happens, and hopefully 5.3.4 will find a solution.

Comment: try php 5.3.5
maybe a 5.3.3 bug

Answer (score 2):

Hola! I had this same problem on both php 5.3.3 and php 5.3.5. My errors read like this on 5.3.5

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      __php_iconv_strlen in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_string in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_strpos in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_appendl in iconv.o
      __php_iconv_appendl in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_substr in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _zif_iconv_mime_encode in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
      _php_iconv_stream_filter_append_bucket in iconv.o
     (maybe you meant: __libiconv_version)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

**the solution is alterations to the file ext/iconv/iconv.c**

open it up and change around line 185 to look like this

- #if defined(HAVE_LIBICONV) && defined(ICONV_ALIASED_LIBICONV)
- #define iconv iconv
- #endif

basically changing "libiconv" to just "iconv"

that solution worked for me on both php 5.3.3 and 5.3.5 on snowleopard 10.6.4

peace

Answer (score 0):

This is one of a class of problems compiling PHP on Mac OS X that relates to multiple versions of libraries -- the PHP developers' response is almost invariably "Just delete the extra libraries. Problem solved" -- completely ignoring the fact that there are often *quite legitimate reasons* to have multiple libs installed. They refuse to address the issue.

This post: http://blog.yimingliu.com/2009/02/24/missing-library-symbols-while-compiling-php-528/

covers the case of libxml, but it's a similar problem.

Comment: 1. PHP does not compile it is interpreted. 2. It is possible to have multiple versions of PHP living side by side. Just make sure that the web server is using the one that you think that it should be using. i.e. correct paths/ `php.ini` files